# How do you navigate once your action has completed with redux-toolkit and createAsyncThunk()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action, redux-toolkit

Defined action `signInUser`:

```js
export const signInUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/loginUser",
  async (user, thunkAPI) => {
    const { username, password } = user;
    try {
      const res = await axios.post("/api/auth/login", { username, password });
      thunkAPI.dispatch(loginUser(res.data));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      thunkAPI.dispatch(setErrors(err.response.data));
    }
  }
);
```

On form submission, `handleSubmit()` dispatches `signInUser()` action.

Component:

```
const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { username, password } = formData;
    try {
      await dispatch(signInUser({ username, password }));
      // DON'T WANT BELOW CODE TO RUN IF signInUser() FAILS (BUT IT DOES)
      navigate("/posts");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
      // NEED THIS CATCH TO RUN IF IT FAILS
    }
  };
```

Navigation is not possible inside of the `signInUser()` action - as far as I know.

So I'm trying to navigate from within the `handleSubmit()` of the `Login` component. But if the `signInUser()` action trips its `catch` (from a failed login) then I don't want to `navigate("/posts")` in the `handleSubmit()`. I think I need it to trip to the catch in the `handleSubmit()` and not execute `navigate("/posts")`.

Or handle it some other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createAsyncThunk` Thunks ***always*** return a resolved Promise with either the `fulfilled` or `rejected` action object inside. See the [Handling Thunk Results](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results) for the full details, but the basic gist is that the returned thunks have an `unwrap` property that extracts the fulfilled `payload` or throw the error object or payload if returned by `rejectWithValue`. See [Unwrapping Result Actions](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions).

Unwrap the returned Promise.

```js
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { username, password } = formData;
  try {
    await dispatch(signInUser({ username, password })).unwrap(); // <-- unwrap Promise
    navigate("/posts");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

If the UI needs either the value or error from the Thunk then these should also be returned.

```js
export const signInUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/loginUser",
  async (user, thunkAPI) => {
    const { username, password } = user;
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post("/api/auth/login", { username, password });
      thunkAPI.dispatch(loginUser(data));
      return data; // <-- return POST response data
    } catch (err) {
      thunkAPI.dispatch(setErrors(err.response.data));
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(err.response.data); // <-- return error payload
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Works good. And does the code look good to you? The try/catch(es), the async/await(s) - or are promises recommended?

Comment: @R.J. You generally shouldn't mix `async/await`|`try/catch` with Promise chains. Typically you should use one or the other. One isn't necessarily recommended, or better, than the other.

Comment: Last one. Is it better to dispatch in the action - w/ thunkAPI.dispatch() ? Or is it better to return the data from the thunk and dispatch in the component's handleSubmit() ?

Comment: @R.J. Depends where you want/need the data. If only the UI needs it, then returning it is fine. If the data needs to be stored then dispatching an action to store it in state, that is also fine. Writing the thunk to do both is fine and covers both use cases. It depends on the use case.